# How do I import external CSS/JS/Images files into a Nodejs server

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to figure it out a solution for a statement of if but I receive the same error in browser (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)).This error occurs when I use a different kind of creating the server :

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const home = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/pages/home.html`, 'utf-8');
const style = app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const pathName = req.url;

  if (pathName === '/' || pathName === '/home') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-type': 'text/html',
    });
    res.end(home);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404, {
      'Content-type': 'text/html',
    });
    res.end("<h1>Who's there ? </h1>");
  }
});

server.listen(3333, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  console.log('are you working on 3333?');
});
```

but If I use this metode the external CSS file is working :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const termen = path.join(__dirname + '/pages/home.html');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(termen);
});

app.listen(3333);

console.log('hai');
```

Any ideea how I can use this 1st method and my external CSS file will be used?

Comment: What you are asking for isn't logical. The first method creates an HTTP server manually, unrelated to Express, so anything you do with Express (such as adding the static file server middleware) is useless. The way to make it work is using the second method (actually using Express), or of course manually implementing a static file server and getting rid of Express, but that sounds unnecessarily cumbersome to me...

Comment: In this example you didnt connect ``app (style)`` and ``server`` . Server is listening by its own, app is not serving anything.